# Trigger SQL Server insertar registro y actualizar un campo de otra tabla

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo dos tablas:

> tblProductos

```
-Id int,  
-Producto varchar(10),  
-Cantidad int
```

> tblVentas

```
-Idventa  
-Idproducto  
-Cantidad int
```

La tabla tblProductos esta relacionado con tblVentas. Lo que quiero realizar es que cuando se aga la venta de un producto se actualice el campo cantidad de la tabla tblProductos. Es decir disminuir la cantidad de productos una vez realizado una venta .
 Lo estoy intentando hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TRIGGER actualiza_cantidad
on tblventas
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE tblProductos set cantidad=cantidad - inserted.cantidad WHERE 
tblventas.id= inserted.id;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que no está accediendo correctamente a las tablas INSERTADO.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[actualiza_cantidad] ON [dbo].[tblventas] 
  AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
   --SET NOCOUNT ON agregado para evitar conjuntos de resultados adicionales
   -- interferir con las instrucciones SELECT.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- obtener el último valor de identificación del registro insertado o actualizado
  DECLARE @ID INT, @CANTIDAD INT
  SELECT @ID = [id], @CANTIDAD = [cantidad]
  FROM INSERTED

  -- Insertar declaraciones para desencadenar aquí
  UPDATE tblProductos 
  set [cantidad] = ([cantidad] - @CANTIDAD) WHERE 
  [dbo].[tblventas].[id]= @ID;

END
```

Espero que te funcione, no lo he probado, lo he escrito en Bloc de Notas, Saludos!

Comment: Gracias, Me ha ayudado bastante.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Triger de ventas de productos descontar stock 
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_updStockventa AFTER INSERT ON detalle_venta
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 UPDATE producto SET stock = stock - NEW.cantidad 
 WHERE producto.id = NEW.idproducto;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Por favor explica cómo y por qué funciona tu respuesta para que programadores menos experimentados puedan aprovecharla. De paso edita tu respuesta para darle formato adecuado (puedes usar Control + K para formatear código